# Join 2 oracle tables via Latitude and Longitude

Tags: sql, oracle

Join latitude and longitude on 2 oracle tables (I know that there was some function in MySQL but not aware of any function which can join lat/long co-ordinates)
Any help will be be much appreciated

Table 1:
ACCOUNT_ID
LATITUDE
LONGITUDE

Table 2:
LATITUDE
LONGITUDE
COUNTRY

Output:

ACCOUNT_ID, COUNTRY

Comment: Joining latitude and longitude is no different to joining any other columns - why do you think they need to be treated differently? Or are you looking for 'close' positions, or some kind of fuzziness? It isn't clear quite what your issue is. What datatypes are you storing them as, just numbers, or something [spatial](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/spatl/spatial-concepts.html)?

Comment: Either you must do a simple join, either you miss to explains some details

Comment: Also, how can you define a country with a single point in space?

Comment: Lat/long column is of datatype NUMBER.
I want to lookup lat/lang co-ordinates based on close positions in my geo table (table 2). Geo table also has Lat/long in NUMBER